# NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I've added android-support-v4.jar in Java Build Path as well as in libs folder. Also, there's no error shown on the line

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Though I'm getting error on the line

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(
        R.drawable.heart_connect).setContentTitle(Consts.NOTIFICATION).setStyle(
        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageValue)).setContentText(messageValue);
```

as:

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle cannot be resolved to a type.
```

I also tried cleaning the project but that did not help. And also to my wonder, I've another project in the workspace with same piece of code and it works perfectly fine. Both projects have same libraries added to them as well.

This tiny stuff is annoying me too much now. Couldn't even guess the reason of error. Do I also need to add the library some other way?

Comment: What do you mean by you've `added android-support-v4.jar in Java Build Path`?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274767/notificationcompat-bigtextstyle-cannot-be-resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274767/notificationcompat-bigtextstyle-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: @VishalAfre Oh, I don't use an age old, unsupported IDE like Eclipse to build Android apps like you do. It isn't a common thing for me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this because I have faced the same issue so that others can find this easily.
We just need to replace the NotificationCompat with Notification like as below

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context).setContentTitle(notificationMessage.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notificationMessage.getVersionMsg())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationMessage.getVersionMsg()));
```